# Make image clickable in email HTML when Image is DIV background-image

Tags: html, html-email

How can I make an image clickable in a HTML email if the image is set as a background-image URL?

Normally, I'd just wrap the DIV in a "a href", but I'm unsure if that works with email clients?

The image is a background-image (as opposed to img) in order to crop it and center it.

```
<table width="230"  cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" align="left" bgcolor="#EEEEEE">
  <tr>
    <td width="15" bgcolor="red">&nbsp;</td>
    <td width="200" bgcolor="959595" align="left" style="padding: 0px;">
        <div style = "height:200px;width:200px;background-image:url('http://www.thisiscolossal.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/01/snow.jpg');background-position: center center;">
    </div>
    </td>
    <td width="15" bgcolor="red">&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Don't use `background-image` in emails - Outlook doesn't support it: https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/

Comment: Why don't you just try to wrap the div with an a? Just make sure to put `style="display: block"` on the a!

Answer (score 2):

Inside the `div` you want to make clickable do the following

```
<a href="/destination" style="display:block; width:100%; height:100%;">&nbsp;</a>
```

This will make the link the size of the whole div.

Keep in mind that different email clients have different support for different CSS rules. You might be better of actually including the image in the body rather than on CSS.

Here is some reference on CSS support by Email Client:
https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/

Comment: Just tested it in gmail. It doesn't work. Just a narrow top part of the image is clickable. If I open the .html file in a browser, then it's fully clickable.

Comment: Keep in mind that support for different CSS rules is different on each email client.  I've uploaded my answer with some reference.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [backgrounds.cm](http://backgrounds.cm) to get bulletproof backgrounds in almost every email client (Div background image not a good idea across client support. Best to use TD).

As for your answer, you could make a transparent PNG image that is the size of your parent element and then use a href on that. Just need to make sure the dimensions match exactly for use with Outlook.

Second option is like previously stated - crop and re upload and use img tag.

Last option is to try and create a transparent "button" (bulletproof buttons - [buttons.cm](http://buttons.cm)) that fits over the background image. This is the least compatible across clients and also makes the least sense to do.